# Jacobi identity as a cocycle condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The Jacobi identity in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ looks like this (for $x,y,z\in \mathfrak{g}$):
$$[[x,y],z]-[x,[y,z]]+[y,[x,z]]=0.$$ This just says that the map $y\mapsto [x,y]$ is a derivation with respect to the Lie bracket $[-,-]$.

It also looks like some sort of cocycle condition. An alternating sum equal to zero. Can this be made precise? Is the Jacobi identity the kernel of some differential?

Comment: Sorry Mariano you probably know but.... This is a complete answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Comments should only be used to clarify the problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the adjoint $\mathfrak{g}$-module $\mathfrak{g}$ we have
$$
Z^1(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g})={\rm Der}(\mathfrak{g}),\quad B^1(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g})={\rm ad}(\mathfrak{g})
$$
for the Lie algebra cohomology. So the map ${\rm ad}(x)$, defined by $y\mapsto [x,y]$ is a $1$-cocycle for the Lie algebra cohomology with coefficients in the adjoint module. In this sense, the Jacobi identity is a derivation condition, which is a $1$-cocycle condition.

In general,
the space of Lie algebra $1$-cocycles and $1$-coboundaries with coefficients in a $\mathfrak{g} $-module $M$ is given by
\begin{align*}
Z^1(\mathfrak{g},M) & = \left \{ \omega \in Hom (\mathfrak{g},M) \mid \omega ([x,y])=
x\cdot \omega (y)-y\cdot \omega(x) \right \}\\
B^1(\mathfrak{g},M) & = \{ \omega \in Hom (\mathfrak{g},M) \mid \omega (x)=x\cdot m
\mbox{ for some } m\in M \}
\end{align*}

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I agree. But the formulation "it looks like some sort of cocycle condition" is not so specific about it, so that I thought, viewing a derivation as a $1$-cocycle is a possibility.